# Using .data() to set variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm trying to set a variable in a form using .data() and cannot get it to work as I cannot get any output for the variable "fee", I only see a blank. 
Ideally the user would select a Type, enter a footage, and then select either 25% or 50%. Each percentage is tied to a different data entry for the Type selected (either hp or lp). Then the data type selected would be plugged into a data() selector to pull out a value for "fee". I can get all the other variable to display an amount except this one so I'm thinking this must be where I'm going wrong.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong so any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/g78bG/2/

HTML:

```
<select class="pSelectP" id="pPost_D">
    <option value="select">Type</option>
    <option data-hp="5" data-lp="2" value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input id="pPost_F" class="pSelectQ" placeholder="Footage" />
<br/>
<select id="pPost_P" placeholder="Percentage">
    <option value="lp">25%</option>
    <option value="hp">50%</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input id="pPost_C" placeholder="Cost" />
<br/>
<input id="pPost_A" placeholder="Total" />
```

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class="pSelectP"] , [class="pSelectQ"]', function () {
    if ($('#manualOverrideNo').prop('checked')) {
        var parts = $(this).attr('id').split("_"),
            service = parts[0],

            footage = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_F").val(),  
                                 10),
            percentage = $("#" + service + "_P").val(),
            fee = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_D").data("'" + 
                  percentage + "'"), 10),
            cost = $("#" + service + "_C"),


            amount = '',
            finalAmount = '';


        if (isNaN(footage)) {
            total.val("Please enter Quantity");
        }

        if (!isNaN(footage) && (!isNaN(Number(fee)))) {
            amount = Math.ceil(footage * fee);
            total.val(amount);
            cost.val(fee);
        }


    }

});
```

Comment: You are missing an element called "manualOverrideNo". Also, parseFloat doesn't take 2 arguments

Comment: Doh. I forgot to take out the manualOverrideNo when I made the JSFiddle but that is not the issue. Thank you pointing that out though. And I had the impression that parseFloat was supposed to be used with a second argument to set what base numbers were going to be used? That was what I had been told and how I have always used it, although I haven't been doing this for long.

Comment: parseInt can take a second argument.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to adjust some of the math, but I think this will work for you.

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class="pSelectP"] , [class="pSelectQ"]', function () {
            var service = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[0],
                footage = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_F").val());
                pricetype = $("#" + service + "_P option:selected").val();
                percentage = parseFloat($('#pPost_D option:selected').data()[pricetype]);
                fee = percentage * footage;

            if (isNaN(footage)) {
                $("#" + service + "_A").val("Please enter Quantity");
            }

            if (!isNaN(footage) && (!isNaN(Number(fee)))) {
                $("#" + service + "_A").val(Math.ceil(fee));
                $("#" + service + "_C").val(fee);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think about going at it through that route. I will check this and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the code out but this is going to multiple the footage by the actual percentage instead of the price tied with the percentage. The percentage listed has almost nothing to do with the actual price (it is a weird set up, I know, but that is how they like it). What I need to multiply the footage by is the low price ("lp", in this case 2) or high price ("hp", in this case 5) that is tied to each service. I could just hard code in each price but there are about a hundred and the prices change every quarter so I'm trying to work smarter instead of harder lol. But thanks though.

Comment: I've updated the code where it will pull the data value from the pPost_D select. See if that better suits your needs. Odd that $('#select option:selected').data('data-foo') doesn't pull anything.